# Call API every 5 seconds using *.kv file

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to call a method every 5 seconds in *.kv file, I have found many examples online using *.py file but unfortunately not even a single using *.kv file. Please help me with this.

***.kv file**

```
 Label:
            id:time
            text: root.display_time()
            font_size:40
            size:[300,50]
```

***.py file (method)**

```
 def display_time(self):
        return ddt.get_time()
```

Comment: maybe you couldn't find example with .kv because probably you can't do this only with .kv and you have to run ie. `Clock.schedule_interval` to run function which will update it periodically.

Comment: @furas He could not find an example in .kv because that is unusual thing to do. In .kv the right side of the colon is python, so you can put python code in there. I am not sure why OP wants that done in .kv. 
I would put that `Clock` function in `__init__` of the parent rule and update a `StringProperty()`.

Comment: @AndreiSima Although the solution mentioned below worked for me, but I still want to know how can we do the same thing with 'Clock function in __init__ of the parent rule and update a StringProperty()'

Comment: @ShamimAhmad  Yes the solution is working and is what you asked for. I only say is odd to follow this route. In terms of code readability and understanding is not that clear what you want to achieve.
Also the way you want it in OP might not be bullet proof since all UI updates must be done in `@mainthread` `you cannot do any OpenGL-related work in a thread` . Just to be sure i decorate any function that might have a suspicion of executing in another thread with `@mainthread` decorator.
Posted what you asked in previous comment. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by assigning the `Clock.schedule_interval()` to a property of the `Label` in the `kv`:

```
#: import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
#: import ddt datetime.datetime
Label:
    abba: Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: setattr(self, 'text', str(ddt.now())), 5)
```

The `abba` property has no effect, except to start the `Clock.schedule_interval()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shamim Ahmad request on comment for OPost:

Please see example for changing kivy properties from python.

You can see that all attributes for the 3rd Label are being set form python side.
In this example i tried to mix multiple properties in order to illustrate how you can interact with your UI from python side. You can expand this example for other Kivy properties.

main.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import random

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.properties import (
    ListProperty,
    ObjectProperty,
    StringProperty,
)
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
Config.set('graphics', 'left', 0)
Config.set('graphics', 'top', 0)

Builder.load_file('main.kv')


class MainLayout (BoxLayout):

    label1_text = StringProperty('Initial Text')
    label2_text = StringProperty()
    label2_color = ListProperty([1, .5, 0, 1])

    my_object_label = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_my_lbls, 5)
        self.refference_time = datetime.now()
        self.label1_text = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')

        self.my_object_label.markup = True
        self.my_object_label.text = '[b]Object Label[/b]'
        self.my_object_label.color = self.random_color()
        self.my_object_label.font_size = '30sp'

    @mainthread
    def update_my_lbls(self, dt):
        self.label1_text = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        time_delta = (datetime.now() - self.refference_time).seconds
        if (time_delta % 2 == 0):
            self.label2_color = [0, 1, .2, 1]
            self.label2_text = f'[b]{str(time_delta)} even [/b]'
        else:
            self.label2_color = [.2, .5, 1, 1]
            self.label2_text = f'[b]{str(time_delta)} odd[/b]'
        self.my_object_label.color = self.random_color()

    def random_color(self):
        r, g, b, a = [random.uniform(0, 1) for _ in range(4)]
        return ([r, g, b, a])


class MyApp (App):

    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<MainLayout>:
    my_object_label: my_object_label
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 10
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgba: (.1, .1, .1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        font_size: '30sp'
        text: root.label1_text
        color: (0, .5, .8, 1)
    Label:
        font_size: '30sp'
        markup: True
        text: '[b]Time Delta[/b]'
        color: root.label2_color
    Label:
        id: my_object_label
```